# How to change SNMP community name of a Zebra ZM600 printer?

Tags: snmp, printer

I want to change SNMP community Name in **Zebra ZM600 printer** from public to private for ex:

snmpwalk -v1 -c **public** "address IP" enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5

when I walk the MIB tree I use public like a name of community , put I want change it to **private** or other name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all I found the solution for this issue,

**first** I create file with [ZPL II commands](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/.../zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) and I called it  **test.zpl**, inside the file I wrote this command :

```
^XA
^NN,,,test,test,test
^XZ
```

**second** I send this file to the printer by FTP with command line:

```
c:> put c:\test.zpl
```

**third** I restart the SNMP into the printer by telnet, and run the MIB tree.

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c CommunityNameHere "address IP" enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5
```